# How to use sed to remove some lines around the specified line?

Tags: sed

I want to remove a maven dependency in all the pom.xml files. 
I know how to remove the line after the specified line but have no idea to remove the lines before the specified line.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>moon</groupId>
  <artifactId>conup-remote-configuration</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1-DU-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To remove lines before a pattern, ideally you will have to read the file twice. Post some sample data so that we can offer a solution that could help you solve your problem.

Comment: You can also use the hold space in **sed**, but we really need to see from where to where you want to cut: fixed number of lines? From pattern A to pattern B?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could process the file backwards, starting with the last line of  the file and ending with the first line of the file.  Something like `tac myfile.txt | sed ... | tac myfile2.txt` tac is cat backwards.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the line before the line with `pattern` hits.

```
awk '!/pattern/ &&  NR>1 {print f} {f=$0} END {print f}' file
```